# angular.js "Hello World" app not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, web

A simple Hello World app I made following various tutorials seams to not want to work. Everything seams correct to me, so can someone please help me? Code is in this [repo](https://github.com/Alpasfly/nodeAndAngularTest)

And here you got it just in case: 
- app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

console.log("Server started on port 8080");

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    console.log("Request get");
});
```

-index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"</script>
            <title>Prueba de AngularJS</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            {{"Hello " + "world"}}
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: `Whole app doesn't work...here's the repo` ... that is just not how define a problem or ask a question here. We don't know if server is running, if errors thrown at either end, if problem is in client or server....far too many possibilities so please do some basic debugging and narrow this down. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Clone and tested, check out my answer below. Watch out for these man.

Comment: you're also not specifying a module name in `ng-app`

Answer (score 1):

This line has no `>`,

```
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"</script>`
```

Replace it with:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
```

In future, see what output you get in *Chrome's* **[View Source](http://www.wikihow.com/View-Source-Code#Chrome_sub)**. That will tell you what's wrong!

And don't add `node_modules`. Add it to `.gitignore`.

Comment: good catch .... goes above and beyond cloning a repo to solve issue. Should not be expected though ... `buy a man a fish, or teach him to fish`

Comment: @charlietfl Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your script tag (inside the html) is missing a closing ">" just after "min.js".
Otherwise it looks fine :)